# Why is QMessageBox.exec() not blocking my thread

Tags: python, multithreading, qt, pyqt

please check below snippet from my application:

```
requestDialogSignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
   def __init__(self):
   ...
   self.requestDialogSignal.connect(self.slotRequestDialog, Qt.QueuedConnection)

def slotRequestDialog():
   mbox = QtWidgets.QMessageBox(QtWidgets.QMessageBox.NoIcon, "title", "message")
   mbox.setStandardButtons(QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Yes | QtWidgets.QMessageBox.No)
   result = mbox.exec()      

def CreateDialogs(self):
   self.requestDialogSignal.emit()
   time.sleep(1)
   self.requestDialogSignal.emit()

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()
window.show()

t = threading.Thread(target=window.CreateDialogs)
t.start()

app.exec()
```

Essentially, what I was trying to achieve is 2nd `QMessageBox` to appear only after first one gets answered. I was expecting the first `QMessageBox` to block the receiver thread on `exec()`, which due to `Qt.QueuedConnection` should not allow for the slot to be called second time. If I change the connection to `Qt.BlockingQueuedConnection` it behaves as expected, although this blocks the sending thread, which is not what I want.

Comment: Using threads in this scenario is wrong, it does not make sense. Also this example shows complete misunderstanding of how exec() works. exec() blocks your code by starting a new event loop and waiting for it to finish. But this event loop still processes all events (!!!) so the second dialog is opened by the event loop which you have started with exec().

Comment: I don't exactly understand why using threads in this scenario is wrong, could You please elaborate? The application of course is more complicated. In this snippet I just wanted to show how I tried to utilize the `Qt.QueuedConnection` to serialize displaying of dialogs.

Comment: Why are threads wrong? Threads are wrong always when you use them een if you do not need them.

Comment: Code containing unnecessary threads and queued connections becomes unmaintainable very soon because its logic becomes incomprehensible once the code grows just a little bigger.

Comment: Your code is very confusing. What is the reason of that signal declaration outside a class? Are the following functions part of the class or not? What's the need for threads (which, by the way, can ***not*** be used for UI objects, as they're not thread safe and the UI thread must always be the main one)? Using blocking functions is also wrong, if you want to emit a signal after a delay use a QTimer, not `sleep`.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this. I have not tested it, as I do not have PyQt nor PySide on my machine. There may be some little issues but the logic is clear and I hope understandable.

```
requestDialogSignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
   def __init__(self):
      self.state = 0 # a state variable which can be used to define the dialog opening logic
      ...

   def openDialog(self):
      mbox = QtWidgets.QMessageBox(QtWidgets.QMessageBox.NoIcon, "title", "message", self) # use self to give the dialog a parent; not strictly needed but it is a good practice
      mbox.setStandardButtons(QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Yes | QtWidgets.QMessageBox.No)
      mbox.finished.connect(self.onDialogFinished) # or you can connect to accepted or rejected signals to finetune the logic
      mbox.open() # open() makes the dialog window-modal but does not block the code

   def onDialogFinished(self):
      self.state += 1
      if self.state == 1: # makes sure we open te dialog only twice, but you can change the logic as you like with the state variable
         self.openDialog()

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()
window.show()
window.openDialog()

app.exec()
```

I believe that the following solution should also work but it is ugly for three reasons. 1) Calling dialog's `exec()` before application's `exec()`. 2) Using too much `exec()`, which is not a good practice. `exec()` should be avoided if possible. 3) Containing an unnecessary recursion... None of these three objections are I believe wrong, they are just ugly and I do not like them.

```
requestDialogSignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
   def __init__(self):
      self.state = 0 # a state variable which can be used to define the dialog opening logic
      ...

   def execDialog(self):
      mbox = QtWidgets.QMessageBox(QtWidgets.QMessageBox.NoIcon, "title", "message", self)
      mbox.setStandardButtons(QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Yes | QtWidgets.QMessageBox.No)
      mbox.exec() # blocks the code until closed
      self.state += 1
      if self.state == 1: # makes sure we open te dialog only twice, but you can change the logic as you like with the state variable
         self.execDialog()

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()
window.show()
window.execDialog()

app.exec()
```

What I find strange about you code is that you show the same dialog twice. Is this really what you want? I guess you actually want to show two different dialogs... and in that case the code would look different. But anyway, I have shown you how to avoid threads and how to properly use (or avoid) `exec()`. I would much vote for using the first of my examples rather than the second.